# Applying macros in other namespace

Tags: file, clojure, macros, namespaces, dsl

I have file with dsl-like stuff data. There I want to declore some s-expression based information. And I have some runner that process such files.

runner.clj

```
 (require '[data :as d])
 ;processing
```

data.clj

```
 (ns  data)
 (defmacro data [s] (println (str s)))

 ;dsl like stuff goes here
 (data "foo")
```

How can I remove non dsl from data file like defmacro?

Also any links to source code with similar solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
; dsl.clj
(ns dsl)
(defmacro data ...)

; data.clj
(ns data
  (:require dsl))

(dsl/data ...)
```

Or with `use`:

```
; data.clj
(ns data
  (:use [dsl :only (data)]))

(data ...)
```